# Reduced in resolution when converting from Visio to PDF in Visio 2013

Tags: office-interop

I have a .NET application that converts Visio files to PDF using the Document.ExportAsFixedFormat method. This works fine in Visio 2010.
However, upon upgrading to Visio 2013, the exact same code is producing PDF with much lower resolution that is unsuitable for print.
I am not sure what is wrong. 
Is there something I can do to export high resolution PDF with Visio 2013?
Thanks!

The following is my code:

```
_app.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(VisFixedFormatTypes.visFixedFormatPDF, // Format
pdfpath, // Output path
VisDocExIntent.visDocExIntentPrint, // Output quality
VisPrintOutRange.visPrintFromTo, // Range
1, // Start page
-1, // End page
false, // Color as black
true, // Include background
false, // Include document properties
false, // Indicate tag structure
true, // Use  ISO 19005-1 (PDF/A).
System.Reflection.Missing.Value // FixedFormatExtClass
);
```

Comment: Try to use the VisPrintOutRange.visPrintAll value instead. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2010/01/26/getting-visio-s-exportasfixedformat-method-to-work-from-c.aspx

Comment: Hi Eugene, I tried using VisPrintOutRange.visPrintAll but there was no difference. Anyway, page range parameters shouldn't affect the PDF quality?

Comment: Try to specify the following arguments: visFixedFormatPDF, "C:\ExportedVisioDocument.pdf", visDocExIntentPrint, visPrintAll . Use the Type.Missing for others. Let me know whether it helps.

Comment: I am using visFixedFormatPDF, visDocExIntentPrint, and visPrintAll. I cannot specify Type.Missing for some of the other arguments, because I am getting compile errors such as "Cannot convert from 'object' to bool".

Comment: After further research, I found out that other people are having the same problem, and it is probably unrelated to office-interop: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-visio/how-to-export-high-resolution-diagram-from-visio/ecb30c96-40a1-4280-a9cf-59b14fffc95f?page=1